# How to create a new measure based on some condition?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a data with columns Profit and Date and I have created 2 new measure.

```
Measure1 = SUM(DF[Profit])
Measure2 = AVERAGE(DF[Profit])
```

I have to create another measure such that it is based on condition i.e.

```
Measure3 = DF[Profit]/Measure1(If Date = 2022-06-01)
           DF[Profit]/Measure2(Else)
```

I want to create a new measure and not a column? Is it possible?

I am under the assumption that it is not possible because in measure3 the numerator is not aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when doing DAX you always has to switch between tables, columns and so-called *scalar value*. In your case, you have to *convert* the `Date = 2022-06-01` using a scalar function.

Most simple way to do it is use an aggregation function to get the value. Like `MAX`

Same goes for `Df[Profit]`, you have to aggregate it.

```
Measure3 =
VAR tmpDate =
MAXX(
    Table,
    Table[Date]
)
RETURN
IF(
    tmpDate = DATE(2022, 06, 01),
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(Df[Profit]),
        Measure1
    ),
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(Df[Profit],
        Measure2
    )
)
```

Note, maybe I would improve the the `tmpDate` as an IF statement that checks that in the current context the date has only one value. Something like:

```
tmpDate =
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(Table[Date]),
    MAXX(
        Table,
        Table[Date]
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```